# Image Recognition - Finding glowing object

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Most game anti-cheat use heuristic approach such as detecting known binaries signature or preventing third party library injection. But, Valve software use [deep learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObhK8lUfIlc) to combat cheat. Valve feed its AI with view angle, fire rate, etc. And its quite working good.

My question is, how do i make such thing but with images instead of data?
Consider this example

Not - Cheat :
[image: not cheat]
[image: not cheat]
[image: not cheat]
[image: not cheat]

Cheating :
[image: cheating]
[image: cheating]
[image: cheating]

Is it possible to make a model like that?

Answer (score 1):

Well images are also just data.
You can seperate each image and its pixels into f.e. its raw numbers for like rgb.
This way you could model a network based on converted inputs of pixels from your image.

In this example, the pattern would probably just recognize huge spikes of those vibrant colors since those value will differ alot from the usual environment.

If the question aims to archive some kind of "visual cheat detection" and is not all about deep-learning, you could simply check the images pixels manually, if you know the color of your "cheat"-overlay or simply detect differences, and flag them this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i like the deep learning approach because every cheat have different visual. So rather than hard coding pixel value, this thing is better. I think recognizing huge spikes of vibrant color is a good solution. Do you know any source so i can read more about this? most of google search is just clickbait article.